# Functions with char as input and a switch statement

Tags: c

Currently trying to do my first "big" set of code where I'm doing a package selection, number of hours input into the system, and a calculation. I'm having issues getting the switch statement to work for me and I think part of this is because I haven't quite grasped the entirety of proper coding with C. I can get the menu to display what I want but when it comes to actually going to the switch statement and the function for whatever package was selected, nothing happens. It just zeros out the code. Any help is greatly appreciated! (sorry for the code looking weird, when I pasted it over it didn't exactly paste the way it's displayed on my screen)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int pkgA()
{
int hours;
int pkgprice= 15; //The package price under 50 hours
int extra_price= 2; //Price per hour over 50 hours

scanf("%i", &hours);
printf("%i\n", hours);

if(hours<=50) //Price under 100 hours
    {
    printf("The total price is:%i", pkgprice);
    }
else if(50<hours<720) //Calculate anything over 50 hours
    {
    int extra_hours=hours - 50;
    printf("%i\n", extra_hours);

    float total_price=extra_hours * extra_price + pkgprice;
    printf("The total price is:$%.2f", total_price);
    }
return 0;

}

int pkgB()
{
int hours; //Input of hours by user
int pkgprice= 20; //The package price under 50 hours
float extra_price= 1.5; //Price per hour over 50 hours

scanf("%i", &hours);
printf("%i\n", hours);

if(hours<=100) //Price under 100 hours
    {
    printf("The total price is:%i", pkgprice);
    }
else if(100<hours<720) //Calculate anything over 100 hours
    {
    int extra_hours=hours - 100;
    printf("%i\n", extra_hours);

    float total_price=extra_hours * extra_price + pkgprice;
    printf("The total price is:$%.2f", total_price);
    }
return 0;
}

int pkgC()
{
int hours;
int pkgprice= 25; //The package price under 50 hours
int extra_price= 1; //Price per hour over 50 hours

scanf("%i", &hours);
printf("%i\n", hours);

if(hours<=150) //Price under 100 hours
    {
    printf("The total price is:%i", pkgprice);
    }
else if(150<hours<720) //Calculate anything over 150 hours
    {
    int extra_hours=hours - 150;
    printf("%i\n", extra_hours);

    float total_price=extra_hours * extra_price + pkgprice;
    printf("The total price is:$%.2f", total_price);
    }
return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
char package_choice;
char package_verify;

do
{
    printf("Which package would you like to select? A, B, or C ");
    scanf(" %c", &package_choice);

    printf("You chose %c, correct?\n", package_choice);
    printf("Y/N\n");

    scanf(" %c", &package_verify);
}while(toupper((unsigned char)package_verify) != 'Y');

printf("You chose package %c.\n", package_choice);

switch(package_choice)
{
    case 'A':
    int pkgA();
    break;
    
    case 'B':
    int pkgB();
    break;
    
    case 'C':
    int pkgC();
    break;
}
}
```

I have tried upper and lower case letters and input them to see if that changes anything but so far nothing has changed the fact the switch statement is just overlooked. Again, thank you for any help!

Comment: `100<hours<720` doesn't do what you think it does. C doesn't have chained comparison operators. It's the same as writing `(100 < hours) < 720`, which will always be true.

Comment: When I ran the code individually for each package it worked within the parameters I had in there. Is there a better way to go about it?

Comment: Please edit your question and fix the code formatting to something used by/readable to every C programmer around the world instead of your invented-just-now personal coding style...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't call functions with their return value

```c
switch(package_choice)
{
    case 'A':
    int pkgA();
    break;
    
    case 'B':
    int pkgB();
    break;
    
    case 'C':
    int pkgC();
    break;
}
```

Should be:

```c
switch(package_choice)
{
    case 'A':
    pkgA();
    break;
    
    case 'B':
    pkgB();
    break;
    
    case 'C':
    pkgC();
    break;
}
```

Comment: Oh, I see now. I got it to go to the function A but it didn't let me go through the code it just gave out a bunch of input for the numbers. When I ran the code individually it worked fine, is there a reason why it might have done that?

Comment: I am just realizing I didn't add a prompt for the hours to be input that is my bad

Comment: @jtward17 not sure, when I'm running it locally by selecting A, B, or C and then inputting a number it seems to work fine. There are some logic issues as Brian mentioned above that might be worth taking a look at.

Comment: Trying out the code with the refactoring above, I did still notice some issues.  For example, what should happen if the user enters in a selection other than 'A', 'B', or 'C'?  When I tried out the code and entered 'D' followed by a 'Y' for package confirmation, the program just ends.

Comment: @NoDakker should I add a do...while loop to correct that?

Answer (score 1):

Since you reached out to me about my comment, I felt I should respond with a possible enhancement to your code to address what appears to be an issue with the program if a user enters an unexpected package selection and the program just ends.  As an example of what my comment was about, here is a scenario the program is probably not expecting.

```
@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/ChoosePackage/bin/Release$ ./ChoosePackage 
Which package would you like to select? A, B, or C D
You chose D, correct?
Y/N
Y
You chose package D.
@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/ChoosePackage/bin/Release$
```

If an unexpected choice is made, the program just ends.  Since the aim of this program is to react to a specific package choice, there might be an additional check to ensure the user entered an expected package entry.  Following is a bit of refactored code within the "do/while" loop to accommodate this.

```
    do
    {
        printf("Which package would you like to select? A, B, or C ");
        scanf(" %c", &package_choice);

        /* Possible suggestion when user does not choose an expected package */

        if (package_choice != 'A' && package_choice != 'B' && package_choice != 'C')
        {
            printf("An unavailable package choice was made\n");
            continue;
        }

        printf("You chose %c, correct?\n", package_choice);
        printf("Y/N\n");

        scanf(" %c", &package_verify);
    }
    while(toupper((unsigned char)package_verify) != 'Y');
```

Following is a test of this refactored bit to illustrate this accommodation.

```
@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/ChoosePackage/bin/Release$ ./ChoosePackage 
Which package would you like to select? A, B, or C D
An unavailable package choice was made
Which package would you like to select? A, B, or C A
You chose A, correct?
Y/N
Y
You chose package A.
65
65
Extra hours: 15
The total price is: $45.00
```

Bear in mind that this is one of many possible methods to add some robustness to the program and it is not intended to promote one type of code etiquette over another.  But you can try this out to see if it meets the spirit of your project.